# Twisted overriding methods?

Tags: python, twisted, overriding

I've recently been learning twisted, so I can integrate the framework into a pygames script.  I've found there are alot of examples and tutorials that override the existing methods in twisted(please correct me if I'm mistaken).

In this simple client I have the `twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.lineReceived` method being overriden when ever a line is sent

```
class ChatClientProtocol(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self,line):
        print (line)

class ChatClient(ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.protocol = ChatClientProtocol

reactor.connectTCP('192.168.1.2', 6000, ChatClient())
reactor.run()
```

Is the `LineReceiver.lineReceived` a listening socket at the address sent to the `reactor.connctTCP`?  Would there be a way to do this without overriding the method?  Or is this the paradigm of twisted(overriding is the way use twisted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LineReceiver.lineReceived` is a method that gets called when a line is received.  I don't know what you mean by asking if it's a "listening socket".

Overriding is the way that you receive lines using `LineReceiver`.  Generally speaking, overriding or implementing callbacks for specific notifications is how you get called in Twisted, yes.  How else would you want to do it?

Comment: The thing with the 'listening socket', was if thats whats going on under the twisted hood?  Its not necessarily about doing it another way but, getting reassured this is an efficient way to go about it.  I was wanting to clarify about `LineReceiver` on a lower level too.